# Where to find specific mechs?

Tags: battletech

I left the complete roster achievement a little too late. I've finished the campaign so all the star systems are now 4-5 skull difficulty; as a result I've collected all the heavy and assault mechs, but finding mediums is a pain. Where can I find medium mechs to get the achievement?

Specifically, I'm still missing the Blackjack, Enforcer and Kintaro.

Comment: Lower skull difficulty missions are still available after completing the campaign.  They're a bit scarce, though.  Try going back towards the area of the map where the campaign started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit late, but better late than never, I guess.

The basic problem with mech collecting is that the base skull rating of all planets increases as you advance the storyline; by the time you get to the end, even the starter systems (with the lowest difficulty) are 3 to 3.5 skulls. The actual contracts you get from a planet have a random spread around the base rating, but (at least in the 1.0 version of the game) this isn't big enough to make a significant difference.

The 1.1 update makes mech collecting much easier, however:

- The spread of difficulties is increased from 0.5 to 1 skull about the base
- There is a separate difficulty level setting, which controls the base skull rating of all planets.

So, what I did was set the difficulty level to "Easy" which reduces the skull ratings for all planets by 1 skull from the default. Then I went back to the starter planets, which were now rated 2.5 to 3 skulls. The actual contracts on offer went as low as 1.5 skulls, but anything with 2.5 or less was usually populated with mediums and lights. After just a couple of hours bouncing around the starter planets, I finished my collection.

Some planets where specific mechs are always for sale:

- Cate's Hold (Magistracy of Canopus): Shadowhawk (both versions)
- Panzyr (Arano Restoration): Griffin
- Smithon (Arano Restoration): Dragon

Answer (score 2):

Even after the campaign is finished, some systems are 3 - 3.5 skulls.  3(ish) skull missions should spawn medium mechs.  I'm not sure if any of those mechs are favored by a given faction, if so, it may be helpful to take missions in those factions area.  For instance, reviewing the entries for the Enforcer and Kintaro at sarna.net shows they were fielded extensively by the Federated Suns, so you might try their space.

Another option is to increase mission variance in the config file.  In your game directory there is a file called SimGameConstants.json.  In that file you can look for the key "ContractDifficultyVariance" and use a higher value so that you get a wider range of mission difficulties.  Lower skulls would have more medium mechs, and increase your odds of finding those specific mechs.

A third option would be to get lucky and find those mechs for sale, but this is far more rare.